# Remove upper part in an image

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am new in tikz, I didn't  want the red boxed part in the below image, I am using the following code. How I change my code ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\DeclareSIUnit{\fahrenheit}{\degree F}
\DeclareSIUnit{\pound}{lbm}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=700,xmax=2000,
      ymin=0,ymax=50,
      axis y line*=left,
      xlabel={$p_0$ (psi)},
      xlabel near ticks,
      ylabel near ticks
    ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `axis y line*=left` to have the y-axis *only* on the left, and applying a similar option, `axis x line*=bottom,` seems to work:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\DeclareSIUnit{\fahrenheit}{\degree F}
\DeclareSIUnit{\pound}{lbm}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=700,xmax=2000,
      ymin=0,ymax=50,
      axis y line*=left,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      xlabel={$p_0$ (psi)},
      xlabel near ticks,
      ylabel near ticks
    ]
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: superb coding. How to change the x axis and y axis value increment by 1 now it's automatically incrementing

Comment: @Kevin: Not sure what you mean? The axis is labelled based on what you have specified as the `xmim` and `xmax`. Not going to look very good if you try to have increments of 1 on the x-axis.  Also, as that is totally unrelated to "removing the upper part of the image", it should be a separate question.